# QGraphicsItem insert ordering setup

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside

Does anybody knows how to make Qt to follows insertion order of Qgraphicsitem while parentItem should be on top!

Note : 
I don't want to do it by zValue, I need it for another job.
Also don't want to make QGraphicsItemGroup for other reasons.

`>` stackBefore should be the solution, but with or without, it draws parent at bottom.

Comment: Try changing the parent with [`setParentItem ( QGraphicsItem * newParent )`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#setParentItem)

Comment: Please post a simplified version of your code that reproduces the issue.